# Installing yeoman on mac

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman

I'm trying to install yeoman on my mac to develop an angular app.

This is my situation:

```
node --version && npm --version

v0.10.33

1.4.28
```

and this is the result of:

```
sh-3.2# npm install --global yo bower grunt-cli
/var/root/.npm-packages/bin/grunt -> /var/root/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
/var/root/.npm-packages/bin/bower -> /var/root/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
/var/root/.npm-packages/bin/yo -> /var/root/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js
```

> yo@1.3.3 postinstall /var/root/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/yo
>   yodoctor
>
> env: node: No such file or directory
>
> npm ERR! yo@1.3.3 postinstall: `yodoctor` npm ERR! Exit status 127 npm
>   ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the yo@1.3.3 postinstall script. npm ERR!
>   This is most likely a problem with the yo package, npm ERR! not with
>   npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     yodoctor npm ERR! You can get their info via: npm ERR!
>   npm owner ls yo npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output
>   above. npm ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0 npm ERR! command "node"
>   "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--global" "yo" "bower" "grunt-cli" npm
>   ERR! cwd /Users/francobasilico npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33 npm ERR! npm
>   -v 1.4.28 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! not ok code 0

I've already tried to find the `cli.js` file but I find lot of them.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and my problem was that I install yo with sudo.

Follow this  [guide](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md) and install yo without sudo privilege. That should fix your problem.

Comment: It worked great!   I had to do source ~/.zshrc instead of source ~/.bashrc

Comment: That's fantastic!!! Tyvm for providing the guide!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have problem with your node version. You should update to 6 or higher.

Yoeman Install prerequisites

Before installing the Fountain Webapp Generator, you will need the following:

- Node.js 6 or higher
- npm 3 or higher (which comes bundled with Node)
- Git

[Yoeman Setup](http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html)